# Excel Rank Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I am using the Excel formula:

```
=IF(M2=0,"",IF(M2>0,SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$162=B2)*($C$2:$C$162=C2),(M2<=$M$2:$M$162)/COUNTIF($M$2:$M$162,$M$2:$M$162))))
```

And I am getting some numbers with decimal point.

I do appreciate your assisting me with this issue.

Thanks and Regards

[image]

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239)

Comment: I'd say you need to include at least a sample of the data in B2:M162

Comment: Department Section Sales   Desired result
Art Paint 8,250  1 1
Art Paint 8,250  1 1
Art Paint 6,750  1.666666667 2
Art Paint 6,750  1.666666667 2
Art Paint 5,500  2.666666667 3
Art Paint 5,250  3.166666667 4
Art Paint 4,000  4.166666667 5
Art Paint 3,750  5.166666667 6

Comment: You need to put that in your Q, above (hint: edit), and tell which cells you have them in; so that the references in the formulas can be located.